# Getting error with new Database in spring boot app

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring

I am having a Java application with SQL server Database. It was working fine. Now we want to migrate to the database to a new DB, and I got a new server name, Port, instance name, and everything needed to connect to the database.

Connection is successful, when trying to execute some query via application, I am getting below error.

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:238)

The client doesn't want any code changes. Pointing to previous DB, or newly migrated Development environment's DB is again working fine. The issue is coming with just this DB.

I am doing the select operation. Below is the model class

```java
    @Entity(name = "EIDPAT")
    public class UserAuthenticate {
    @Id
    @Column(name="UserPin")
    private String userPin;
    
    @Column(name="FirstName")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="MiddleName")
    private String middleName;
    
    @Column(name="LastName")
    private String lastName;
    
    
    @Column(name="Email")
    private String emailAddress;

    }
```

Repo class

```java
    public interface UserAuthenticateRepository extends 
    CrudRepository<UserAuthenticate, String> { }
```

Service Class

```java
    public UserAuthenticate findUser(String userPin) {
        return userAuthenticateRepository.findOne(userPin);
    }
```

aad-database-configuration.xml

```xml
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="SqlCon" 
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
       <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/jdbc/PAT/pat_ds"/>
    </bean>
        
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="SqlCon"></property>  
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="namedParameterTemplate" 
     
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.core. 
    namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="SqlCon"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>  
    
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa. 
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
    ">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="SqlCon"></property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" 
    >
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mmm.aad.model"> 
    </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop 
    key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>            
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

Comment: Hi. As the name suggests, SQLGrammarException is thrown when you are sending an invalid query to the database. Please add more details (query, entities, db types, application.properties). Afraid we cannot help otherwise. Most likely it is a problem with IDs or relationships defined in the entity classes.

Comment: Have updatted the post, everyting is working fine with previous DB and other environment's new DB. There is something different in this DB